# Accessing Resource File with Culture in WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, culture

I am writing an app where the textblocks can display comments in different languages. I am attempting to use "Culture" which I really don't understand.

[image]

I have followed a few videos but still get then same error message:

[image]

Here are the namespace I have added:

```
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Resources;
```

I am just testing the concept out before adding the switch statement:

```
        CultureInfo cult = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");

        Assembly lingua = Assembly.Load("Bailing Calculator");

        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Bailing Calculator.Resources.Res", lingua);

        tbkPHDiameter.Text = rm.GetString("phDia", cult);
```

Am I simply not giving the correct path to the ResourceManager? Thanks for the ensuing onslaught of education!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to be seems like:

```
  CultureInfo cult = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

  Assembly lingua = Assembly.Load("Bailing Calculator");
  ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(string.Format("Bailing_Calculator.Resources.{0}",cult.Name), lingua);
tbkPHDiameter.Text = rm.GetString("phDia");
```

and update the Resource File name to be your target Culture name:
so the file name becomes looks like: `en-US`

Comment: I have copy and pasted your code.I still get the same alarm.

Comment: did you re-named the resource file in Solution explorer from en.resx to en-Us.resx? i updated the answer also, because the space not supported in namespaces.

Comment: I made the adjustments. Same alarm. What should the build action be set to?

Comment: let it as default when add new item it should be Embedded Resource

Comment: That was it! I had jacked with the build types when trying to figure the thing out. Thanks for the code!